# UICollectionViewCell with image without custom Class

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

there pretty simple Question actually:
I want a collectionView with an Image with the same size as the Cell. I want to do this all without building a extra class, so from storyboard (maybe, if I get on my subview?!)

And btw, i load data from web, so I Can't just add a new ImageView every time....

just wanna ask if this is possible?!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have static Collection view then you can do without custom class
but you have dynamic Collection view then you need to create custom class.
which is look like this.

```
class AddAlbumCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imgv: UIImageView!
}
```

In your Collection view Delegate method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddAlbumCell
      cell.imgv.image = images[indexPath.row] //"images" contains image name array
      return cell;
}
```

Comment: glad to help you.